# How to fix "too few arguments to function"?

Tags: c++

my program is given below

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int sum(int x,int y)
{
    return x+y;
}
int sub(int x,int y)
{
    return x-y;
}
int pro(int x,int y)
{
    return x*y;
}
int quo(int x,int y)
{
    return x/y;
}

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    char op;
    cout<<"Enter two numbers:"<<endl;
    cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<"Enter a operator:"<<endl;
    cin>>op;
    switch(op)
    {
    case '+':
        sum(a,b);
        cout<<sum()<<endl;
        break;
    case '-':
        sub(a,b);
        cout<< sub()<<endl;
        break;
    case '*':
        pro(a,b);
        cout<< pro()<<endl;
        break;
    case '/':
        quo(a,b);
        cout<< quo() <<endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout<<"Invalid Operator"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

here is the error i receive

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
C:\Users\amohe\Desktop\cal.cc||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\amohe\Desktop\cal.cc|33|error: too few arguments to function 'int sum(int, int)'|
C:\Users\amohe\Desktop\cal.cc|4|note: declared here|
C:\Users\amohe\Desktop\cal.cc|37|error: too few arguments to function 'int sub(int, int)'|
C:\Users\amohe\Desktop\cal.cc|8|note: declared here|
C:\Users\amohe\Desktop\cal.cc|41|error: too few arguments to function 'int pro(int, int)'|
C:\Users\amohe\Desktop\cal.cc|12|note: declared here|
C:\Users\amohe\Desktop\cal.cc|45|error: too few arguments to function 'int quo(int, int)'|
C:\Users\amohe\Desktop\cal.cc|16|note: declared here|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

need solution.

Comment: Start with the first error message. Read it. Then explain what is unclear about it.

Comment: Hint: collect return value of all the functions. `sum(a,b);
        cout<<sum()<<endl;` to `cout<<sum(a,b)<<endl;`

Comment: ... or output the result directly     
        `cout<<sum(a,b)<<endl;`

Comment: What are you telling the compiler with the line `sum(a,b);`?

Comment: If I count lines correctly, then the shown code is not the one causing the error messages.... Nitpicking, sorry. But you should make sure that shown code is a [mre]. Identifying error-causing lines with `/* error here */` is a good practice on StackOverflow, among other things because sometimes (helpful) edits change the number of lines and thereby the line numbers.

Comment: Amoka Varshan, please let me know how I can make my answer more helpful to you.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the quite clear error message, including the line number, then you will notice that it does NOT complain on

```
    sum(a,b);
```

But it DOES complain on

```
    cout<<sum()<<endl;
```

The difference is rather striking.

You need to give enough parameters to the second one.
Also the first one is useless, compilers tend to tell you that if you increase the warning level.

A solution is to not only calculate and ignore it, instead output it directly and corrctly by using a gentle mixture of your two code lines.

```
    cout<<sum(a,b)<<endl;
```

Comment: Well actually my code has the problem in line 34 and line 33 is the one with parameters, but that I account to having a different number of empty lines somewhere. You might want to edit your question and identify the line with the error. In short, I admit to assuming something in my answer...

Comment: Since the remaining errors (sub(), pro(), quo()) occur at the proper distance and look  all the same, I won't argue about 33 or 34.